# Pandas - Comparing two Dataframe and finding difference

Tags: python, pandas

I have two Dataframes with some sales data as below:

df1:

```
prod_id,sale_date,new
101,2019-01-01,101_2019-01-01
101,2019-01-02,101_2019-01-02
101,2019-01-03,101_2019-01-03
101,2019-01-04,101_2019-01-04
```

df2:

```
prod_id,sale_date
101,2019-01-01,101_2019-01-01
101,2019-01-04,101_2019-01-04
```

I am trying to compare the above two Dataframe to find dates which are missing in df2 as compared to df1

I have tried to do the below:

```
final_1 = df1.merge(df2, on='new', how='outer')
```

This returns back the below Dataframe:

```
prod_id_x,sale_date_x,new,prod_id_y,sale_date_y
101,2019-01-01,101_2019-01-01,,
101,2019-01-02,101_2019-01-01,,
101,2019-01-03,101_2019-01-01,,
101,2019-01-04,101_2019-01-01,,
,,101_2019-01-01,101,2019-01-01
,,101_2019-01-04,101,2019-01-04
```

This is not letting me compare these 2 Dataframe.

Expected Output:

```
prod_id_x,sale_date_x,new
101,2019-01-02,101_2019-01-02
101,2019-01-03,101_2019-01-03
```

Comment: @anky_91 trying to find whats missing between the 2 Dataframes, inner would only matching rows in the 2 Dataframes.

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: @jezrael, updated the initial post with the expected output..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicates`

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```